# Backbone.js : view object is 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Here is my code for a basic Todo app in backbone.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Hello World in Backbone.js</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
    #todoapp ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    #todo-list input.edit {
      display: none;
    }
    #todo-list .editing label {
      display: none;
    }
    #todo-list .editing input.edit {
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <section id='todoapp'>
    <header id='header'>
      <h1>Todos</h1>
      <input id='new-todo' placeholder='What needs to be done?'>
      <div>
        <a href="#/">all</a> |
        <a href="#/pending">pending</a> |
        <a href="#/completed">completed</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section id='main'>
      <ul id='todo-list'></ul>
    </section>
  </section>

  <script type='text/x-handlebars-template' id='item-template'>
    <div class='view'>
      <input class='toggle' type='checkbox' {{checked}}>
      <label>{{ title }} </label>
      <input class='edit' value='{{ title }}'>
      <button class='destroy'>remove</button>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict'

    var App = {
      Models: {},
      Collections: {},
      Views: {},
      Router: {}
    }

    App.Models.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
        title: '',
        completed: false,
        checked: ''
      },
      toggle: function(){
        var completed = !this.get('completed')
        this.save({
          completed: completed,
          checked: completed ? 'checked' : ''
        });
      }
    });

    App.Collections.TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: App.Models.Todo,
      localStorage: new Store('backbone-todo'),
      completed: function(){
        return this.filter(function(todo){
          return todo.get('completed');
        });
      },
      remaining: function(){
        return this.without.apply(this, this.completed());
      }
    });

    App.Views.Todo = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'li',
      template: Handlebars.compile($('#item-template').html()),
      render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.input = this.$('.edit');
        return this;
      },
      initialize: function(){
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
      },
      events: {
        'dblclick label': 'edit',
        'keypress .edit': 'updateOnEnter',
        'blur .edit': 'close',
        'click .toggle': 'toggle',
        'click .destroy': 'destroy'
      },
      edit: function(){
        this.$el.addClass('editing');
        this.input.focus();
      },
      updateOnEnter: function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
          this.close();
        }
      },
      close: function(){
        var value = this.input.val().trim();
        if(value){
          this.model.save({title: value});
        }
        this.$el.removeClass('editing');
      },
      toggle: function(){
        this.model.toggle();
      },
      destroy: function(){
        this.model.destroy();
      }
    });

    App.Views.TodoList = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '#todoapp',
      filter: '',
      initialize: function() {
        this.input = this.$('#new-todo')
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
        this.collection.fetch();
      },
      events: {
        'keypress #new-todo': 'createTodoOnEnter'
      },
      createTodoOnEnter: function(e) {
        if(e.which !== 13 || !this.input.val().trim()){
          return;
        }
        this.collection.create(this.newAttributes());
        this.input.val('');
      },
      addOne: function(todo){
        if(this.filter === 'completed'){
          return;
        }
        var view = new App.Views.Todo({model: todo});
        $('#todo-list').append(view.render().el);
      },
      addAll: function(){
        this.$('#todo-list').html('');
        switch(this.filter){
          case 'pending':
            _.each(this.collection.remaining(), this.addOne);
            break;
          case 'completed':
            _.each(this.collection.completed(), this.addOne);
            break;
          default:
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
            break;
        }
      },
      newAttributes: function(){
        return {
          title: this.input.val().trim(),
          completed: false
        }
      }
    });

    var todoList = new App.Collections.TodoList;
    var todoListView = new App.Views.TodoList({collection: todoList});

    App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        '*filter': 'setFilter'
      },
      setFilter: function(params){
        todoListView.filter = params.trim() || '';
        todoListView.addAll();
      }
    });


    var router = new App.Router;
    Backbone.history.start();

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the `addOne` method of `App.Views.TodoList`, the condition `if(this.filter === 'completed')` causes the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`. Why is `this` (the todoListView object) undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to figure out addOne's caller.

It seems there are 4 usage.

```
this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
```

You passed this as context. This should be ok.

The error you ask is should be one of below usages.
If you want to use this as View object in function, pass this in _.each.

```
_.each(this.collection.remaining(), this.addOne);
_.each(this.collection.completed(), this.addOne);
```

to

```
_.each(this.collection.remaining(), this.addOne, this);
_.each(this.collection.completed(), this.addOne, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

`_.each()` can take an optional context.  Try this:

```
 case 'pending':
    _.each(this.collection.remaining(), this.addOne, this);
    break;
  case 'completed':
    _.each(this.collection.completed(), this.addOne, this);
    break;
```